# How do I save a custom class object data model to a different file each time it is made in java?

Tags: java, android, save

I have a custom ListView that uses an object class for its data. The users can add new items to the listview, the arraylist is then saved in SharedPreferences. However, I also want to save each individual item so that I can use it in another Expandable ListView, how could I create a file for each individual item the user creates, or perhaps there is a better why to do it? Thanks in advance. Here is the object class:

```
 public class Item implements Serializable{
 String homework, date, classes;

    public Item(String homework, String date, String classes){
        this.homework = homework;
        this.date = date;
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public String getHomework(){
        return homework;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public String getClasses(){
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a database?There is a bit of setting up, but after the initial set up writing/reading data is very easy.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Ye a database sounds like a good idea, I'll read through what you linked, do you have any other good tutorials?

Comment: If you don't know how databases work you should read up about them or watch this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgiCxe-ZW8o
Once you understand databases, tables, and queries, the link I gave you before should be sufficient to help you build it in android.

Answer (score 0):

An example of serialize-deserialize class

```
public final class Serialize
{
  private static final String className = Serialize.class.getName();

  public static void save(Object saveThis, String serializeFileName, Context context)
  {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try
    {
      if(saveThis != null)
      {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(serializeFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(saveThis);
      }
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      //log it
    }
    finally
    {
      if(oos != null)
      {
        try{oos.close();}catch(Throwable t){}
      }
      if(fos != null)
      {
        try{fos.close();}catch(Throwable t){}
      }
    }
  }

  public static Object read(String serializeFileName, Context context)
  {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object readThis = null;

    try
    {
      File file = context.getFileStreamPath(serializeFileName);
      if(file != null && file.exists())
      {
        fis = context.openFileInput(serializeFileName);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        readThis = ois.readObject();
      }
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      //log it
    }
    finally
    {
      if(ois != null)
      {
        try{ois.close();}catch(Throwable t){}
      }
      if(fis != null)
      {
        try{fis.close();}catch(Throwable t){}
      }
    }

    return readThis;
  }

  public static boolean delete(String serializeFileName, Context context)
  {
    boolean deleted = false;
    try
    {
      File file = context.getFileStreamPath(serializeFileName);
      if(file != null && (file.exists()))
      {
        deleted = file.delete();
      }
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      //log it
    }

    return deleted;
  }

  public static boolean exist(String serializeFileName, Context context)
  {
    boolean exist = false;
    try
    {
      File file = context.getFileStreamPath(serializeFileName);
      if(file != null && (file.exists()))
      {
        exist = true;
      }
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      //log it
    }

    return exist;
  }
}
```

Use the `save` method to save the serializable object in a file and the `read` method to read it.